# Tkinter change Font with hotkey

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Newbie question.  I am trying to change the font in the Text widget via hotkey.
so that the text after the hotkey is pressed changes font without affecting the previous text.  I assume this will be done with tags, but have not found anything online that explains these well enough.

Comment: You need to be more specific. As written your question is too broad. What part of the question are you struggling with? Do you know how to change fonts? Do you know how to find functions to events?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what "hotkey" you would like use to change the font.

Most of the keys on a keyboard are designed to alter the text, so I will assume it is CTRL + "keyValue". ALT + "keyValue" would work too.

In this example shown below, the CTRL key must be toggled on in order to use the hotkeys. The hotkeys are "1", "2", and "3".

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Example')

textBox = Text(root, height=2, width=30)
textBox.pack(ipadx = 100, ipady=100)

ctrl_key = False

def key(event):
    global ctrl_key 

    if event.keysym == "Control_L":
        ctrl_key = not ctrl_key 

    if ctrl_key == True:
        textBox.configure(state="disabled")
        if event.char == "1":
            textBox.config(font=("Helvetica"))
        if event.char == "2":
            textBox.config(font=("Courier"))
        if event.char == "3":
            textBox.config(font=("Times"))
    else:
        textBox.configure(state="normal")

root.bind_all('<Key>', key)
root.mainloop()
```

This line disables the textBox, so no more text can be added. To enable back, simply just change from "disabled" to "normal".

```
textBox.configure(state="disabled")
```

Comment: Sorry if i was not specific enough, I know how to change the font of the whole widget, but cannot figure out how to accomplish multiple fonts in a single text widget bound to hotkeys.